# Retrieving ListBox.column values and store into objects

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know there must be a better way to perform the above sub than using multiple `If` statements. I was thinking of storing the `obj.PropertName` into a collection and run it through a `for` loop.

```
'Create instance
Dim wellObj As CWell
Set wellObj = New CWell
```

.
.
.

```
Private Sub Well_List_Click()

    'Must check if null..
    If Not (Well_List.Column(1, row) = "") Then
        wellObj.wellName = Well_List.Column(1, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(2, row) = "") Then
         wellObj.wellActive = Well_List.Column(2, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(3, row) = "") Then
         wellObj.wellDiameter = Well_List.Column(3, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(4, row) = "") Then
         wellObj.wellCasing = Well_List.Column(4, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(5, row) = "") Then
         wellObj.screenedInterval = Well_List.Column(5, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(6, row) = "") Then
         wellObj.wellSock = Well_List.Column(6, row)
    End If

    If Not (Well_List.Column(7, row) = "") Then
        wellObj.wellDepth = Well_List.Column(7, row)
    End If

End Sub
```

**Refactored:**

NB: wellObj has all properties type `String`

```
Private Sub Well_List_Click()

    Dim properties(1 To 7) As String
    Dim value As String
    Dim row As Integer

    'Skip header
    row = Well_List.ListIndex + 1

    'Must check if null..       
    properties(1) = "WellName"
    properties(2) = "WellActive"
    properties(3) = "WellDiameter"
    properties(4) = "wellCasing"
    properties(5) = "ScreenedInternal"
    properties(6) = "WellSock"
    properties(7) = "WellDepth"

    For i = 1 To 7
        value = Well_List.Column(i, row)
        If value <> vbNullString Then 
            CallByName wellObj, properties(i), VbLet, value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with proper indentation. There shouldn't be anything (other than subroutine/line labels) at the same level of indentation as a `Private Sub` statement, other than the `End Sub`.

Code blocks are more readable and code as a whole is easier to follow when code blocks are indented. General rule of thumb, if there's an `End X` for a statement, you're in a code block. Give that <kbd>Tab</kbd> key some lovin'!

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
|...If Not FooBar Then
|...|...DoSomethingElse
|...End If
End Sub DoSomething
```

---

Using a `For..Next` loop here is tricky, because you're accessing a different property every time. You're going to need to access the properties by name, and to do that you need them in an indexed structure, like an array:

```
Dim properties(1 To 7) As String
properties(1) = "wellName"
properties(2) = "wellActive"
properties(3) = "wellDiameter"
properties(4) = "wellCasing"
properties(5) = "screenedInternal"
properties(6) = "wellSock"
properties(7) = "wellDepth"
```

Now you can go from 1 to 7 and, assuming `CWell` is a class module (I'm not all that familiar with Access, I hope my assumption is correct)...

```
For i = 1 To 7
    value = Well_List.Column(i, row)
    If value <> vbNullString Then SetPropertyValue wellObj, properties(i), value
Next
```

---

Notice I'm using `vbNullString` instead of an empty string literal `""`. `vbNullString` is a *null string pointer*, which isn't allocated a memory address. `""` has its own memory spot. No biggie, but not needed either.

---

So, how would that `SetPropertyValue` method be implemented? The VBA standard library has this little wonder in its `VBA.Interaction` module, called `CallByName`:

```
Private Sub SetPropertyValue(ByRef instance, ByVal member, ByVal value)
    CallByName instance, member, vbLet, value
End Sub
```

This is assuming `CWell` exposes a `Property Let` accessor/mutator. If `wellName` and friends are public fields, you need to properly encapsulate them and expose them via properties.

That said, public members should be `PascalCase`, so "wellName" would be "WellName".

---

Now, I really introduced that `SetPropertyValue` method just to make an abstraction level for the sake of this answer. The one-liner could just as well be inlined:

```
Dim properties(1 To 7) As String
properties(1) = "wellName"
properties(2) = "wellActive"
properties(3) = "wellDiameter"
properties(4) = "wellCasing"
properties(5) = "screenedInternal"
properties(6) = "wellSock"
properties(7) = "wellDepth"

For i = 1 To 7
    value = Well_List.Column(i, row)
    If value <> vbNullString Then 
        CallByName wellObj, properties(i), vbLet, value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yay for `for` loops. Thé solution for this case.

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I did some preliminary test and it worked perfectly. CallByName is a lifesaver! Thanks

Comment: @Jabberbyter "`CallByName` is a lifesaver" ...[**indeed!**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63004/23788)