# TestExplorer 2.0 - From Grid to TreeView

Tags: c#, mvvm, xaml, rubberduck

Rubberduck's unit testing feature (heck, the whole project) started with a [VBA unit testing framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63004/23788) that was ported from [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23); the VBA logic was pretty much simply rewritten in another language, and a dockable toolwindow is now available in the VBA IDE for Rubberduck users around the world:

[image: Rubberduck 1.x Test Explorer]

For the next major release, the Test Explorer is getting a facelift. What was a WinForms user control in 1.x is going to be a WPF user control in 2.x - in fact as much as possible of the UI is going to be redone in WPF/XAML, and hosted in a WinForms/WPF control host.

[image: Rubberduck 2.0 Test Explorer]

Here's the markup for the Rubberduck 2.0 Test Explorer:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Rubberduck.UI.UnitTesting.TestExplorerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.UnitTesting"
             xmlns:unitTesting="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UnitTesting"
             xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="255" d:DesignWidth="255"
             MinWidth="255" MinHeight="255" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:TestExplorerViewModel}">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
        </Style>

        <unitTesting:TestOutcomeImageSourceConverter x:Key="OutcomeIconConverter" />

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="OutcomeGroupViewSource" Source="{Binding Model.Tests}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Outcome" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TestMethodTemplate" DataType="{x:Type unitTesting:TestMethod}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" 
                       Source="{Binding Outcome, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeIconConverter}}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Margin="4" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Text="{Binding QualifiedMemberName}" 
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="OutcomeTemplate" 
                                    DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestMethodTemplate}">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="4" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="4" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=({0})}" 
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="64" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="48"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Background="#FFEEF5FD" />

        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">

            <Button Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
                <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/arrow-circle-double.png" />
            </Button>

            <Separator />

            <Menu>
                <MenuItem VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.Run}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/control.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RunAllTestsCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_RunAllTests}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/flask--arrow.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RunNotExecutedTestsCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_RunNotRunTests}" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/question-white.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RunPassedTestsCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_RunPassedTests}" >
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/tick-circle.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RunFailedTestsCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_RunFailedTests}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/cross-circle.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RepeatLastRunCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_RunLastRunTests}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/arrow-repeat.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>

                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.Add}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/flask--plus.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddTestModuleCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_AddTestModule}">
                    </MenuItem>
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddTestMethodCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_AddTestMethod}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/flask.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddErrorTestMethodCommand}" Header="{x:Static resx:RubberduckUI.TestExplorer_AddExpectedErrorTestMethod}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/flask--exclamation.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Separator />

            <Button Command="{Binding CopyResultsCommand}">
                <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/document-copy.png" />
            </Button>

            <Button Command="{Binding ExportResultsCommand}">
                <Image Height="16" Source="../../Resources/disk.png" />
            </Button>

        </ToolBar>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="2">
            <StackPanel>

                <Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0">
                    <ProgressBar Height="12" 
                                 Background="DimGray" 
                                 Foreground="LawnGreen"
                                 Maximum="{Binding Model.TestCount, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                 Value="{Binding Model.ExecutedCount, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Border>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <TreeView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="TestMethodTree"
                  MouseDoubleClick="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OutcomeGroupViewSource}, Path=Groups}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OutcomeTemplate}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TreeView>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" Height="5" ShowsPreview="True" Cursor="SizeNS" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Border Grid.Row="4" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="DimGray">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MinHeight="48" Background="Gainsboro">
                <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Result.Outcome, Converter={StaticResource OutcomeIconConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.QualifiedMemberName}" FontWeight="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="32,0,0,0" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Result.Output}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="DarkSlateGray"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

One concern I have, is that I'm calling `ICollectionView.Refresh()` *everytime a test finishes*, which doesn't feel like it's optimal, especially given that I'm passing the `TestMethod` object that has just executed... but I haven't managed to get the groupings to refresh using that `test` parameter in `UpdateTestMethod`. Is it a problem to leave the unused parameter in place?

```
public partial class TestExplorerControl : UserControl
{
    public TestExplorerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContextChanged += TestExplorerControl_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void TestExplorerControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldValue = e.OldValue as TestExplorerViewModel;
        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            oldValue.TestCompleted -= ViewModel_TestCompleted;
        }

        var newValue = e.NewValue as TestExplorerViewModel;
        if (newValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        newValue.TestCompleted += ViewModel_TestCompleted;
    }

    private void ViewModel_TestCompleted(object sender, TestCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTestMethod(e.Test);
    }

    private TestExplorerViewModel Context { get { return DataContext as TestExplorerViewModel; } }

    private void UpdateTestMethod(TestMethod test)
    {
        var view = (CollectionViewSource)Resources["OutcomeGroupViewSource"];
        view.View.Refresh();
    }

    private void TreeView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selection = Context.SelectedItem;
        if (selection == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Context.NavigateCommand.Execute(selection.GetNavigationArgs());
    }
}
```

And here is the `TestExplorerViewModel`, which is assigned to the `DataContext` of the XAML control:

```
public class TestExplorerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ITestEngine _testEngine;
    private readonly TestExplorerModelBase _model;

    public TestExplorerViewModel(VBE vbe, ITestEngine testEngine, ICodePaneWrapperFactory wrapper, TestExplorerModelBase model)
    {
        _testEngine = testEngine;
        _testEngine.TestCompleted += TestEngineTestCompleted;
        _model = model;

        _navigateCommand = new NavigateCommand(wrapper);

        _runAllTestsCommand = new RunAllTestsCommand(testEngine, model);
        _addTestModuleCommand = new AddTestModuleCommand(vbe);
        _addTestMethodCommand = new AddTestMethodCommand(vbe, model);
        _addErrorTestMethodCommand = new AddTestMethodExpectedErrorCommand(vbe, model);

        _refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRefreshCommand, CanExecuteRefreshCommand);
        _repeatLastRunCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRepeatLastRunCommand);
        _runNotExecutedTestsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRunNotExecutedTestsCommand);
        _runFailedTestsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRunFailedTestsCommand);
        _runPassedTestsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRunPassedTestsCommand);

        _copyResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCopyResultsCommand);
        _exportResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteExportResultsCommand);
    }

    public event EventHandler<TestCompletedEventArgs> TestCompleted;
    private void TestEngineTestCompleted(object sender, TestCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = TestCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }

    private TestMethod _selectedItem;
    public TestMethod SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private readonly ICommand _runAllTestsCommand;
    public ICommand RunAllTestsCommand { get { return _runAllTestsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addTestModuleCommand;
    public ICommand AddTestModuleCommand { get { return _addTestModuleCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addTestMethodCommand;
    public ICommand AddTestMethodCommand { get { return _addTestMethodCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addErrorTestMethodCommand;
    public ICommand AddErrorTestMethodCommand { get { return _addErrorTestMethodCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _refreshCommand;
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get { return _refreshCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _repeatLastRunCommand;
    public ICommand RepeatLastRunCommand { get { return _repeatLastRunCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _runNotExecutedTestsCommand;
    public ICommand RunNotExecutedTestsCommand { get { return _runNotExecutedTestsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _runFailedTestsCommand;
    public ICommand RunFailedTestsCommand { get { return _runFailedTestsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _runPassedTestsCommand;
    public ICommand RunPassedTestsCommand { get { return _runPassedTestsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _copyResultsCommand;
    public ICommand CopyResultsCommand { get { return _copyResultsCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _exportResultsCommand;
    public ICommand ExportResultsCommand { get { return _exportResultsCommand; } }

    private readonly NavigateCommand _navigateCommand;
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get { return _navigateCommand; } }

    private bool _isBusy;

    public bool IsBusy 
    { 
        get { return _isBusy; }
        private set
        {
            _isBusy = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        } 
    }

    public TestExplorerModelBase Model { get { return _model; } }

    private void ExecuteRefreshCommand(object parameter)
    {
        if (_isBusy)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsBusy = true;
        _model.Refresh();
        SelectedItem = null;
        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private void EvaluateCanExecute()
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    private bool CanExecuteRefreshCommand(object parameter)
    {
        return !IsBusy;
    }

    private void ExecuteRepeatLastRunCommand(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        _testEngine.Run(_model.Tests.Where(test => test.Result.Outcome != TestOutcome.Unknown));
        IsBusy = false;
        EvaluateCanExecute();
    }

    private void ExecuteRunNotExecutedTestsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        _testEngine.Run(_model.Tests.Where(test => test.Result.Outcome == TestOutcome.Unknown));
        IsBusy = false;
        EvaluateCanExecute();
    }

    private void ExecuteRunFailedTestsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        _testEngine.Run(_model.Tests.Where(test => test.Result.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed));
        IsBusy = false;
        EvaluateCanExecute();
    }

    private void ExecuteRunPassedTestsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        _testEngine.Run(_model.Tests.Where(test => test.Result.Outcome == TestOutcome.Succeeded));
        IsBusy = false;
        EvaluateCanExecute();
    }

    private void ExecuteExportResultsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ExecuteCopyResultsCommand(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For this to work, I changed the `TestMethod` class to derive from `ViewModelBase` (to get the nifty `OnPropertyChanged()` magic), and made it implement `IEditableObject` - the actual logic didn't need to change:

```
public class TestMethod : ViewModelBase, IEquatable<TestMethod>, IEditableObject
{
    private readonly ICollection<TestResult> _assertResults = new List<TestResult>();
    private readonly IHostApplication _hostApp;

    public TestMethod(QualifiedMemberName qualifiedMemberName, VBE vbe)
    {
        _qualifiedMemberName = qualifiedMemberName;
        _vbe = vbe;
        _hostApp = vbe.HostApplication();
    }

    private readonly QualifiedMemberName _qualifiedMemberName;
    private readonly VBE _vbe;
    public QualifiedMemberName QualifiedMemberName { get { return _qualifiedMemberName; } }

    public QualifiedModuleName QualifiedModuleName { get { return _qualifiedMemberName.QualifiedModuleName; } }

    public void Run()
    {
        _assertResults.Clear(); //clear previous results to account for changes being made

        TestResult result;
        var duration = new TimeSpan();
        try
        {
            AssertHandler.OnAssertCompleted += HandleAssertCompleted;
            duration = _hostApp.TimedMethodCall(_qualifiedMemberName);
            AssertHandler.OnAssertCompleted -= HandleAssertCompleted;

            result = EvaluateResults();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            result = TestResult.Inconclusive("Test raised an error. " + exception.Message);
        }

        Result = new TestResult(result, duration.Milliseconds);
    }

    private TestResult _result = new TestResult(TestOutcome.Unknown);

    public TestOutcome Outcome { get { return _result.Outcome; } }

    public TestResult Result
    {
        get { return _result; } 
        set { _result = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    void HandleAssertCompleted(object sender, AssertCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _assertResults.Add(e.Result);
    }

    private TestResult EvaluateResults()
    {
        var result = TestResult.Success();

        if (_assertResults.Any(assertion => assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed || assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Inconclusive))
        {
            result = _assertResults.First(assertion => assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed || assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Inconclusive);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public NavigateCodeEventArgs GetNavigationArgs()
    {
        try
        {
            var moduleName = QualifiedMemberName.QualifiedModuleName;
            var methodName = QualifiedMemberName.MemberName;

            var module = _vbe.VBProjects.Cast<VBProject>()
                .Single(project => project == QualifiedMemberName.QualifiedModuleName.Project)
                .VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>()
                .Single(component => component.Name == QualifiedMemberName.QualifiedModuleName.ComponentName)
                .CodeModule;

            var startLine = module.get_ProcStartLine(methodName, vbext_ProcKind.vbext_pk_Proc);
            var endLine = startLine + module.get_ProcCountLines(methodName, vbext_ProcKind.vbext_pk_Proc);
            var endLineColumns = module.get_Lines(endLine, 1).Length;

            var selection = new Selection(startLine, 1, endLine, endLineColumns == 0 ? 1 : endLineColumns);
            return new NavigateCodeEventArgs(new QualifiedSelection(moduleName, selection));
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(TestMethod other)
    {
        return QualifiedMemberName.Equals(other.QualifiedMemberName);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is TestMethod
            && ((TestMethod)obj).QualifiedMemberName.Equals(QualifiedMemberName);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return QualifiedMemberName.GetHashCode();
    }

    private TestResult _cachedResult;

    private bool _isEditing;
    public bool IsEditing { get { return _isEditing; } set { _isEditing = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        _cachedResult = new TestResult(Result, Result.Duration);
        IsEditing = true;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        _cachedResult = null;
        IsEditing = false;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        if (_cachedResult != null)
        {
            Result = _cachedResult;
        }

        _cachedResult = null;
        IsEditing = false;
    }
}
```

Should I have implemented a separate class? Does `GetNavigationArgs` belong there?

Anything else?

Comment: How about invalidating the control's display rather than forcing a redraw immediately?

Comment: @Mario yes, absolutely. I just haven't managed to get that to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TestMethod**

The `Result` property (and `IsEditing` property)

> ```
> public TestResult Result
> {
>     get { return _result; } 
>     set { _result = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
> }
> ```

seems only to be set by the `TestMethod` object, so there is no need to have a `public` setter there. Making the setter either `private` or `protected` will increase its encapsulation.

The usage of `OnPropertyChanged()` should only be done if the property really changed, so changing it to

```
public TestResult Result
{
    get { return _result; } 
    private set 
    { 
        if(_result == value) { return; }
        _result = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

will remove unneeded calls of said event.

---

> ```
> private TestResult EvaluateResults()
> {
>     var result = TestResult.Success();
>
>     if (_assertResults.Any(assertion => assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed || assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Inconclusive))
>     {
>         result = _assertResults.First(assertion => assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed || assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Inconclusive);
>     }
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Here you are first checking with `Any()` if the wanted item exists and later you are calling `First()` to retrieve the first item.

A much easier way would be to just use `FirstOrDefault()` and using the null coalescing operator to return either the found item or `TestResult.Success()` like so

```
private TestResult EvaluateResults()
{
    var result = _assertResults.FirstOrDefault(assertion => assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Failed || assertion.Outcome == TestOutcome.Inconclusive);

    return result ?? TestResult.Success();
}
```

---

> ```
> public override bool Equals(object obj)
> {
>     return obj is TestMethod
>         && ((TestMethod)obj).QualifiedMemberName.Equals(QualifiedMemberName);
> }
> ```

I don't like the usage of `is` together with a cast because it is just doing the cast two times. A better way would be to use `as` together with a `null` check like so

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var method = obj as TestMethod;
    if (method == null) { return false; }

    return method.QualifiedMemberName.Equals(QualifiedMemberName);
}
```

---

> ```
> public void CancelEdit()
> {
>     if (_cachedResult != null)
>     {
>         Result = _cachedResult;
>     }
>
>     _cachedResult = null;
>     IsEditing = false;
> }
> ```

here the setting of `_cachedResult` to `null` should be done inside the `if`. There is no need to set an object which is `null` to `null`.